# How run trained tflite model for urbansound 8k dataset using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, classification, tflite

I have trained a audio classification model URBANSOUND8k and converted it into tflite file how can we run the model for diffrent audio other than dataset

code to run tflite model file . Audio Classification